# change the state from componentWillReceiveProps affect the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

here is my code of componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
console.log('45', next)
if (this.props.favList) {
  this.setState({ favRest: this.props.favList })
  console.log('setting state',this.state)
}
else
  if(this.props.EventList) {
  this.setState({ loading: false, EventList: this.props.EventList });
}
}
```

when the state is changes through `this.props.favList` it show changes in console of state is changed but that state is not affected in the render method ...in render mehod it shows the previous state

Answer (score 0):

`this.props` are the current props (before the update) and the first parameter on  `componentWillReceiveProps` are the *new* props that the component is getting. This is what you want:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
  console.log('45', next)
  if (next.favList) {
    this.setState({ favRest: next.favList })
    console.log('setting state',this.state)
  }
  else
    if(next.EventList) {
    this.setState({ loading: false, EventList: next.EventList });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React 16.3 you can use getDerivedStateFromProps which in the new lifecycle method willReceiveProps is being deprecated for. As per the other answers you have access to next props which will have the updated value available for mapping to state. So your code above would be as follows:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log('45', nextProps)
    if (nextProps.favList) {
        return {
            favRest: nextProps.favList
        }
     } else if (nextProps.EventList) {
         return {
             loading: false,
             EventList: nextProps.EventList
         }
    }
    return null;
}
```